# $N$-Port Network connectivity matrix versus reflection coefficient

Tags: network

For a $N$-port network, if there are $x$ number of internal ports and $y$ number of external ports, we define a connectivity matrix which relates all internal ports to each other. The symbol usually used for this connectivity matrix is $[Γ]$. This is also the same symbol used for reflection coefficient of a 2-port network. Are these two terms the same with only difference being that connectivity matrix is a matrix while reflection coefficient is a complex term?

Also, return loss is defined as -20log(Γ). This is the reflection coefficient at whichever port we want to find the return loss, correct?

Comment: would you please define formally what you mean by a "connectivity matrix", I do not recall having met this concept before.

Comment: Connectivity matrix basically defines how one port relates to another. For example let's say port 2 is connected to port 3. Then V2+ = V3- (both in same direction on the same line). It is used to explain how internal ports of a system (those not under our control to give input or receive output) are related to each other.